# Search for dynamic key values in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, key-value

I feel like i'm missing something quite simple. What are some of the best ways to iterate through combinations of $key names -- doing something different for each-- in a php foreach loop?

I have a number of values in an array with key values that follow the same naming format.

Example:

```
$rec_items['title3'] = implode($meta['title3']);
$rec_items['title4'] = implode($meta['title4']);
$rec_items['title5'] = implode($meta['title5']);
```

The `$rec_items` array also contains other values that do not follow this naming convention (or data type).

I'm looping through `$rec_items` with a foreach loop. I would like to be able to dynamically cycle through key names in $rec_items, and 'do something' when a key is found that matches `title*`. I've tried pushing numeric numbers from a counter variable into key names to be searched for (like below):

```
foreach ($rec_items as $key => $value){
    $c = 0;
    if(!empty($key[${'title'.$c}]){
        $c++;
        //do something


}
```

I believe that I cannot pass the value `${'title'.$c}` into `$key[]` and have tried to pass the value of `${'title'.$c}` as a string with no luck.

I just share the above to try to highlight what i'm trying to achieve.

(1) dynamically loop through key names in the format 'title*'

(2) if the key name is present in the `$rec_items` array ... do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your original code was trying for; you appeared to be treating the array key like an array itself? Using a variable variable? Anyway, you just need a simple string search of the key. You can use regular expressions or whatever you like for more complex matching.

```
<?php
$rec_items = ["foo"=>12, "bar"=>34, "title1"=>56, "title2"=>78, "baz"=>90];
foreach ($rec_items as $k=>$v) {
    if (strpos($k, "title") === 0) {
        echo "$k = $v\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
title1 = 56
title2 = 78
```

Comment: Took me a bit. But realized the mistaken understanding behind my trying to iterate through results of foreach like they are an array. Your response works in a sense. But later realized preg_match seems to be the way to go for using regex. Thanks for the response!